# Wireless gate closure software/hardware combo

Tags: wireless, home-automation, electronics

I have a small fence around my house with 2 small gate doors that latch closed. These are gates for people, not cars.

I would like to find an affordable software / hardware combo to let me know if either of the gate doors are not closed.

I let my dog run around in the yard but sometimes delivery people let themselves in without my realizing it and they fail to close the gate behind them. If this happens my dog could get out and get hit by a car or lost.

It seems like it should be a simple thing to construct, but I don't have as much experience with or time for home built electronics as I would like. Ideally I could get a notification on my phone if the gate is open, but even just a doorbell-like alarm would be fine.

Comment: https://www.google.com.sg/amp/www.instructables.com/id/Low-power-doorwindow-sensor/ looks about right. Or an automatic door closer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks much. Do they sell it? I am not looking to build anything. For this question I am looking for a sensor not an automatic door closer. Thanks again.